# parsing xml find last element with matching attributes

Tags: python, xml, parsing, xpath, python-3.4

I have some poorly written xml that I'm trying to loop through and extract the test name, start, and end time of each test. I use that data to append a column to a csv. My current implementation checks every element in the xml and seems to be slow.

Here is a an xml example

```
<ProcessStart Id="1" Type="MemTest" Name="WriteRead" Options=" /pi=5 /m=AA" Tick="1233" />
<ProcessStart Id="2" Type="MemTest" Name="WriteRead" Options=" /pi=5 /m=AA" Tick="1233" />
<ProcessStart Id="3" Type="MemTest" Name="WriteRead" Options=" /pi=5 /m=AA" Tick="1233" />
<ProcessEnd Id="1" Tick="7553"/>
<ProcessEnd Id="2" Tick="7553"/>
<ProcessEnd Id="3" Tick="7553"/>
<ProcessStart Id="17" Type="MemTest" Name="WriteRead" Options=" /pi=25 /m=AA" Tick="8126" />
<ProcessStart Id="18" Type="MemTest" Name="WriteRead" Options=" /pi=25 /m=AA" Tick="8127" />
<ProcessStart Id="19" Type="MemTest" Name="WriteRead" Options=" /pi=25 /m=AA" Tick="8127" />
<ProcessEnd Id="17" Tick="12873"/>
<ProcessEnd Id="18" Tick="12873"/>
<ProcessEnd Id="19" Tick="12873"/>
```

Trying to figure out how to get the Id value for the processStart that matches the name and options. So far I have:

```
root.find('ProcessStart[@Name="%s"][last()]' % test_name).get('Id')
```

but rather than checking the last element that matches the test name it check the last element of the processStart. How do I address this? Or would the fastest way to extract this information be reading the input file line by line?

***New Information***
I want to return the Id value where Id=3. This is the last value where all ProcessStarts with matching Name and Options exist. The current count shown immediately references the last instances of ProcessStart then checks the name and options conditions. I am looking for a way to find the last ProcessStart with matching conditions.

Perhaps a better example would be to match by options as name is the same for this instance so:

```
options=" /pi=5 /m=AA"
test_id=root.find('ProcessStart[@Options="%s"][last()]' % options).get('Id')
```

Using this example and this data set it will return an error 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get' I believe this is because the last element doesnt match the options. However I'm trying to target the last ProcessStart with matching options.

COMPLETE CODE:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

#Read the xml file
tree = ET.parse('C:/Users/mkaminski/Desktop/sample.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

#get the first option
test_option=root.find('ProcessStart').get('Options')
test_id=root.find('ProcessStart[@Options="%s"][last()]' % test_option).get('Id')
```

COMPLETE XML FILE:

```
<AppLog App="RPx" Version="0.6.1" BaseVer="0.0.1" Time="20160208153547" Tick="0">
  <RPxTest TestName="Tests/WriteRead" LongName="WriteRead_b=0_pi=5_m=AA_i=0" Instances="16" Memory="49534849024" Options=" /pi=5 /m=AA" IdRange="1-17" Tick="1233" />
  <ProcessStart Id="1" Type="MemTest" Name="WriteRead" Options=" /pi=5 /m=AA" Tick="1233" />
  <ProcessStart Id="2" Type="MemTest" Name="WriteRead" Options=" /pi=5 /m=AA" Tick="1233" />
  <ProcessStart Id="3" Type="MemTest" Name="WriteRead" Options=" /pi=5 /m=AA" Tick="1233" />
  <ProcessEnd Id="1" Tick="7553"/>
  <ProcessEnd Id="2" Tick="7553"/>
  <ProcessEnd Id="3" Tick="7553"/>
  <RPxTest TestName="Tests/WriteRead" LongName="WriteRead_b=0_pi=25_m=AA_i=0" Instances="16" Memory="49534849024" Options=" /pi=25 /m=AA" IdRange="17-33" Tick="8126" />
  <ProcessStart Id="17" Type="MemTest" Name="WriteRead" Options=" /pi=25 /m=AA" Tick="8126" />
  <ProcessStart Id="18" Type="MemTest" Name="WriteRead" Options=" /pi=25 /m=AA" Tick="8127" />
  <ProcessStart Id="19" Type="MemTest" Name="WriteRead" Options=" /pi=25 /m=AA" Tick="8127" />
  <ProcessEnd Id="17" Tick="12873"/>
  <ProcessEnd Id="18" Tick="12873"/>
  <ProcessEnd Id="19" Tick="12873"/>
</AppLog>
```

ERROR:

```
File "C:/Anaconda3/Scripts/samle.py", line 9, in <module>
    test_id=root.find('ProcessStart[@Options="%s"][last()]' % test_option).get('Id')

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Comment: Please show a complete, but minimal sample of your input document and all of the necessary (which means, only the necessary) Python code to reproduce your problem. Help: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: Your command looks fine.  What is it returning, and what do you want it to return?  If you want to get the Id change `.get('Tick')` to `.get('Id')`.

Comment: MathiasMüller That xml format is repeated to create a large xml file. That sample should show what i'm trying to accomplish. 

@Matthew was too long to add in comment added in edit

Comment: _"That sample should show what i'm trying to accomplish"_ - no it doesn't. Show a small, but complete input XML sample, and all the necessary Python code (as I have told you already). Then, show the exact output you expect from running this Python code.

Comment: @MathiasMüller

There it is

Comment: If I understand the problem, you need to generate the CSV-file  based on the initial XML?

If so, I would have do it on the XSLT-transformation and used for this very simple XSL-template.  In this template in one variable you can get all nodeset of start tag, the second variable - all nodset of trailing tags sorted in the order of ID.

<xsl: foreach> for presorted 'ProcessStart' tags allow to you to generate output CSV-file and get attributes of 'ProcessStart' corresponding to the attributes 'ProcessEnd'

Comment: I have to use values from this XML and test it against conditions given in another CSV file and append them if they are within a certain range. I will look into that and see if that would be more expedient to first compose a csv then manipulate the data as a dataframe. Thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that you are running into a limitation in ElementTree's xpath support (which is not complete).  Using lxml your command works perfectly.

To do this with ElementTree, retrieve all of the matching elements and let Python select the last one.

Change

```
options=" /pi=5 /m=AA"
test_id=root.find('ProcessStart[@Options="%s"][last()]' % options).get('Id')
```

To

```
options=" /pi=5 /m=AA"
test_id=root.findall('ProcessStart[@Options="%s"]' % options)[-1].get('Id')
```

In this command, we get all matching *ProcessStart* elements (in order) as a list, and grab just the last one.  Then we can grab the id.

Comment: Thank you that answers my question perfectly I'm glad you were able to understand what I was trying to convey. Thanks for you time.

Comment: @kaminsknator I hope it is clear to you now that you _had_ to show the Python code for Matthew to be able to understand your problem. Please keep this in mind for future questions.

Comment: Can you add a simplified example for finding the last element? This one seems a bit complex

Comment: @StevenVascellaro Do you mean a simpler problem than the OP asked, or a simpler answer?  If the former, you will need to ask a new question with the problem that you need to solve.  If the latter, this is about as simple as it gets with the OP's problem.

Comment: @Matthew The question being asked is how to find the last element with matching attributes. For others with the same issue, it may be simpler to read `last_match = root.findall('Element[@Attribute="Value"]'`

Comment: @StevenVascellaro You still have to substitute value somehow, and this will find all the matches, not the last one.  Using your approach, you'd have to do `expression = "Element[@Attribute='{}']".format(options)`, followed by `all_matches = root.findall(expression)`, and finally `last_match = all_matches[-1]`.  I'm not sure that I'd call this simpler.  Additionally, the OP wanted to extract the Id field on the element, so I'd need to do `test_id = last_match.get('Id')`.